# Cannot connect to any HTTPS url on iOS 11 simulator

Tags: ios, https, ios-simulator, ios11, xcode9

Going to https://google.com results in the screen below.

This is an iOS 11.0.1 simulator, and I'm using Xcode 9.0.1

I've tried multiple HTTPS urls, and none have worked.

I've tried these fixes, to no avail:

- Restart the simulator
- `Hardware > Erase All Content and Settings`

The date/time of the simulator is correct.

[image]

Comment: Are you with any proxy ?

Comment: @Jack Nope, no proxy.

Comment: Try one trick, in MacBook settings remove your wifi/Ethernet connection and add it again...

Comment: @Jack Didn't help

Comment: is other simulator's (SE,8 x) works?

Comment: @Jack The X simulator wasn't working. Haven't tested the others. I also tried an iOS 9.3 simulator and got the same issue.

Comment: @Jack Looks like it was Avast antivirus and its "Web Shield" feature messing with me. :(

Answer (score 2):

After trying an iOS 8.4 simulator, I noticed the simulator had no internet connection. With a quick Google search, I found that Avast antivirus has a "Web Shield" feature that is mucking with the simulator. Disabling that fixed my problem!

Weird that both iOS 9.3 and iOS 11.0.1 weren't showing the same error message regarding the internet connection. Very misleading!

Answer (score 0):

The anti-virus on your computer could be causing this issue. The web shield scanning for unsecured or private connections is not letting the WebKit or SafariViews to load any urls.

If your computer is running Avast:

Try unchecking the "Scan for secured connections" in the preference tab / shields tab / settings link at Web Shield row

Hope that helps!