# login.microsoftonline.com does not work using Xcode 9 simulators

Tags: objective-c, xcode9, appauth, sfauthenticationsession

Anyone using AppAuth 9.1 and Xcode 9? I have successfully used the SFAuthenticationSession to call my desired login page, which then redirects me to login.microsoftonline.com.. However, I get this blank page instead.

I have no issues running on my ios 10.2 devices or had any issues with Xcode 8 simulators. Open to suggestions!

[image]

Update: I noticed that all the info after login.microsoftonline.com is missing. But am unsure whats the cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find my answer after looking at other angles. Link can be found here

[Cannot connect to https url on ios 11 simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939564/cannot-connect-to-any-https-url-on-ios-11-simulator)